# Embedding video with Play Framework and JW Player

Tags: javascript, html, video, playframework, jwplayer

I am trying to embed videos using the Play Framework and JW Player.  I can hard code and make it work just fine, but I want to use the model's class to determine the video file (via path) that will be embedded.

Here is the code I have been playing with, but is not working:

```
<script src="@{'/public/jwplayer/jwplayer.js'}"></script>
```

---

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var content = ${_post.content};
    setVideo(content)
    });
</script>
```

---

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    function setVideo( content )
    {
        jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
            'flashplayer': "@{'/public/jwplayer/player.swf'}",
            'file': content,
            'controlbar': 'bottom',
            'width': '640',
            'height': '480'
        });
    }
</script>
```

Honestly, this is probably more of pseudo code at this point... But hopefuly it is clear what I am *trying* to do here:

1. Retrieve the content of the post (in the case the content will be
   the path to the video)
2. Place that into the function.
3. Which will set the 'file': content.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas for tackling the issue:

1. is the Path visible in the rendered HTML?
2. is it visible in the generated javascript?
3. does it need to be escaped correctly? i'd image your `var content` should be a string?
4. how does the `_post.content` get generated? why the underscore? are you doing this from within a play template tag?
5. is the file accessible via said path, outside of the script?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This does give me some ammunition to try and tackle this problem when I get home from work this evening.  I will respond with my progress.

Comment: The fix was really quite simple, and it was your third idea on the list.
I had to capture it as a string:
`var content = "${_post.content}";`